# How to avoid making a flat list for reading each line using Openpyxl?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am using `openpyxl`, could someone tell me how to make a new list when reading next line?

I don't want to have flat list.

Code:

```
import openpyxl


excel_filename = "sample.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_filename, data_only=True)
my_sheet_name = "Sheet1"
ws = wb[my_sheet_name]

print("File: {}".format(excel_filename))
data=[]
for j in range(1, ws.max_row+1 ):
    for i in range(1,ws.max_column+1):
        ihidden = ws.row_dimensions[j].hidden
        svalue = ws.cell(column=i,row=j).value
        if ihidden == True:
            shidden = "HIDDEN"
        else:
            shidden = "VISIBLE"

            data.append(svalue)

print(data)
```

Sample.xlsx:

[image]

Output:

```
File: sample.xlsx
[1231231, None, None, 3123, 123123, None, 123, 21322, None]
```

I hope it can be:

```
File: sample.xlsx
[[1231231, None, None],[3123, 123123, None],[123, 21322, None]]
```

Comment: You don't know why you do not get rows and columns? You append everything to the same `data` list.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```py
data = [[ws.cell(column=j,row=i).value for j in range(1,4) if not ws.row_dimensions[j].hidden] for i in range(1,4) if not ws.row_dimensions[j].hidden]
print(data)
```

**Output**

```
>>> [[1231231, None, None], [3123, 123123, None], [123, 21322, None]]
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for trying to help! But something wrong for data[j].append(svalue) |
It says: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Use `ws.iter_rows(values_only=True)`